# How to check if 2 files are empty in perl using if condition

Tags: files, scripting, perl

```
if(-z "$file1" && "file2") {
  print "file1 and file2 are empty";
} else {
 print "execute";
}
```

When I write this, when the files are empty it prints `execute` and when files are not empty it prints
`file1 and file2 are empty`.

When the condition is true it is supposed to print `file1 and file2 are empty`, am I right? or wrong?

Comment: What's your issue with the current code, apart from missing an `-z` in the `if` statement?  This is not clear from the text in the question.  What are you expecting the code to do and how does the code not do that?

Comment: I am expecting that when file1 and fle2 are empty the if condition is true and hence it should print file1 & file2 are empty but it doesn't do that instead it prints execute and when the if condition is false it prints file1 and file2 are empty

Comment: If the code prints `execute`, then one or both of your files are not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `-z` and `$` in `-z "$file2"`. Also, you do not need to quote the file names (this does not cause the bug, though). Run the tests below using a Perl one-liner as an example:

```
rm -rf foo bar
touch foo
perl -le 'my $file1 = "foo"; my $file2 = "bar"; if ( -z $file1 && -z $file2 ) { print "file1 and file2 are empty"; } else { print "execute"; }'
# File 'bar' does not exist, so -z $file2 evaluates to false:
# execute

rm -rf foo bar
touch foo bar
perl -le 'my $file1 = "foo"; my $file2 = "bar"; if ( -z $file1 && -z $file2 ) { print "file1 and file2 are empty"; } else { print "execute"; }'
# Both files exist and are zero size, so both '-z' tests evaluate to true:
# file1 and file2 are empty

rm -rf foo bar
touch foo bar
echo '1' > bar
perl -le 'my $file1 = "foo"; my $file2 = "bar"; if ( -z $file1 && -z $file2 ) { print "file1 and file2 are empty"; } else { print "execute"; }'
# File 'bar' iz non-zero size, so -z $file2 evaluates to false:
# execute
```

Comment: I did try this, doesn't work though. Is there an alternate way?

Comment: @SumanValsange Updated the answer with several tests, all confirmed to work. Let me know what output you get when you run these.

Comment: Just a question - Does this also work if the file1 and file2 is closed before checking this?

Comment: @SumanValsange The test will be true if the file sizes are zero. Whether or not the files are open should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `-z` in the `if` statement.

```perl
if ( -z "$file1" && -z "$file2" ) {
    print "file1 and file2 are empty";
}
else {
    print "execute";
}
```

Comment: Okay I did add this and try, it works the same way. Kindly make me understand what it shd print in this scenario if file1 and file2 are empty

Comment: -z returns true when the file is empty. So -z "$file1" && -z "$file2" returns true when both files are empty, that is, execute if, otherwise execute else.